# wordpress, loading posts IN page (shorthand code?)

Tags: wordpress, posts

I have never used wordpress as a cms for a site so please forgive my obliviousness. I tried to google this for a bit with no luck, I think I am either phrasing this wrong or thinking about it incorrectly.

I have page on wordpress that I would like to feed in a bunch of "news" posts. Can I code this within the actual page (like the text input section). How would I go about doing this. Is it possible to have a plugin or some shorthand code that would feed in all the posts with a certain category, and further more is this possible to do within just the general page editor (just within the wp-admin panel). Again, sorry for my obliviousness, I feel like this is probably a pretty simple answer, but I haven't worked on wordpress in years.

Thank you for your time!! Any points to the right direction would be incredibly helpful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try:

```
[display-posts tag="advanced" posts_per_page="20"]
```

This will list the 20 most recent posts with the tag ‘Advanced’.

For more options, check this: http://en.support.wordpress.com/display-posts-shortcode/

Comment: This is what i was looking for thank you so much! Can I just put this in the "text" portion of the page editor? Does anything need to be activated for the shortcode to work?